# which is the best table(asp.net table or HTML) to use when table contain Telerik rad controls and labels?

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik

I have a requirement where i am working with telerik rad controls.
currently i am using asp.net table for that purpose.
I heard using html table is good since asp table have viewstate which will make page heavy.
 Please find sample image[image]

I am supposed to use telerik controls(textbox,dropdown etc)
these thing are querying from DB and sending values to DB.
for design Purpose i am making use of CSS also.
Can any any one suggest me which table is best in my case.Can i make use of CSS with HTML table?

please suggest .thank you

Comment: Whatever you feel more comfortable with. They both render a <table> tag in the HTML markup. I don't think asp:Table stores anything in the ViewState by itself, yet you can always disable it, should you need to.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to check size of page after disabling viewstate on table

Comment: Use the browser dev toolbar

Comment: can you specify more details about that because i am not familiar

Comment: You can inspect the DOM and compare the size of the ViewState hiddne field. Or, you can use the network tab and monitor the overall size of the aspx page. Google a bit.